# Whats the difference declaring variables with and without prototypes

Tags: javascript

Whats the difference between (via prototypes)

```
var Todo = {};

Todo.prototype.name = "...";
Todo.prototype.hello = function() { ... }
```

Vs (variables & functions "outside" object)

```
var Todo = {}
Todo.name = "..."
Todo.hello = function() { ... }
```

Or even the below : variables & functions in object

```
var Todo = {
    name: "...",
    hello = function() { ... }
}
```

Comment: example 2 and 3 are almost identical

Comment: The first one doesn't even work since object-instances don't have a prototype property by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think it like

A property or a function declared with prototype is an instance member of Todo.

A property or a function declared without prototype is a static member of Todo.

Answer (score 2):

The first one doesn't make sense as you are dealing with an object instance (`({}) instanceof Object === true`), it won't have a `prototype` property (`Object` does).

You may be inquiring about the difference between these two patterns...

```
var ObjA = function() {
    this.method = function() {};
};

var ObjB = function() {};

ObjB.prototype.method = function() {};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36ZGp/).

The former will use more memory when instantiated - each object has their own `method`. The latter won't each have their own `method`, the `method` lives on the `prototype` object, which is the next in command on the prototype chain when its attempted to be accessed on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

`Todo.prototype` is also an object, so the difference is if you declare property with prototype, then every object who created from this prototype will have the property, otherwise, the property is only for `Todo` the object self.

Answer (score 0):

A significant difference between method #1 and #2 (which is almost identical to example #3) is on `new` keyword that you need to use if you extend your function via prototype, e.g.

```
var Todo1 = function() {};
Todo1.prototype.name = "Foobar";

var Todo2 = {name: "Foobar" }

var a = Todo1;
console.log(a.name); // no property retrieved

var b = Todo2;
console.log(b.name); // Foobar

var c = new Todo1;
console.log(c.name); // Foobar
```